# Not inserting into database. PHP and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, post, updating

I have to create a form where answers get sent to the database but when I fill in the form the database is not updating and I have getting the self made error :"something went wrong". Can anyone see anything wrong? Thanks.

Form:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="sentEnquiries.php" name="enquiries">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">
                            Name</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" required="required" /></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">
                            Email Address</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                            </span>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" required="required" /></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="phoneNumber">
                            Phone Number</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>
                            </span>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" name="phone" placeholder="Enter phone number" required="required" /></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="partySize">
                            Party Size</label>

                        <input type="number" min="1" max="6" class="form-control" id="partySize" name="partySize" required="required" />
                    </div>




                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="arrivalDate">
                            Arrival Date</label>

                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="arrivalDate" name="arrivalDate" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="departureDate">
                            Departure Date</label>

                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="departureDate" name="departureDate"/>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">
                            Message</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="9" cols="25" required="required"
                            placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-skin pull-right" id="btnContactUs">
                        Send enquiry</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

Answers:

```
   <?php

include("conn.php");


 $sentName = $_POST['name'];
$sentEmail = $_POST['email'];
$sentPhone = $_POST['phone'];
$sentPartySize = $_POST['partySize'];
$sentArrivalDate = $_POST['arrivalDate'];
$sentDepartureDate = $_POST['departureDate'];
$sentMessage = $_POST['message'];


$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Enquiries(enquiryID, name, email, phone,   partySize, arrivalDate, departureDate, message) VALUES(NULL, '$sentName', '$sentEmail', '$sentPhone, '$sentPartySize', $sentArrivalDate, '$sentDepartureDate', '$sentMessage')";


?>
```

Further down answers doc:

```
<div class="descriptions">

        <?php
        if(mysqli_query($conn, $insertQuery)) {
            echo "<p>Thank you for your enquiry.</p>";
                mysqli_close($conn);
        } else {
            echo "<p>Something went wrong.</p>";
                mysqli_close($conn);
        }


        ?>




        </div>
```

Comment: Havent looked for the error, but your application won't be save to SQL injections. Use prepared statements to make them save ;)

Comment: you cant use `name` on insert value change this to something else. and the ID should be auto increment anyway so remove these also.

Comment: @Option which value? inside the post?

Comment: @Twinfriends doing security last cheers!

Comment: And why you'll do this last? You just dublicate your work. Take you the time to look at prepared statements. May it'll take an hour, but you'll save sooo much time. Or you wan't to rewrite your whole application when its finished just for security reasons? Poeple often work as you do... and then at the ending they don't care about security and just publish the project without any security. It really doesn't surprise me why so many data can be stolen so easy.

Comment: @tbh its an assignment, we have't learned much about security yet and its worth the least percentage, also getting it tight so I had to leave it but yeah I know what you mean

Comment: Oh okay. Yeah so I understand you totally :P But for the future, if you're interested take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp its really well written and nothing complicated. May it will save you some points ;)

Comment: thanks! @Twinfriends

Answer (score 0):

could you make sure as below :

1. enquiryID column, is this column is auto increment if not better you set the id become auto increment primary key
2. For debug purposes, can you echo first in $_POST['name'] then exit; to make sure that the post data from your html is work correctly.
3. if that not work, you should try to select first from database with simple query, so you will know the connection to database table is work correctly

Comment: 1. yeah it is both 2.how would I got about doing that? Not being doing this much as you can prob tell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i'd do it.

Change yours as required but here's my example:

PDO class:

```
class form
{
    public function sendForm($name, $email, $phone, $party, $date, $depart, $message)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `enquiries` (`name`,`email`,`phone`,`partySize`,`arrivalDate`,`departureDate`,`message`) VALUES (:fname, :email, :phone, :party, :arrive, :depart, :msg)");
        $stmt->bindParam(array(':fname' => $name, ':email' => $email, ':phone' => $phone, ':party' => $party, ':arrive' => $date, ':depart' => $depart, ':msg' => $message));
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Then within your form page:

```
$form = new form();

if (isset($_POST['sendIt']))
{
    $form->sendForm($_POST['Fname'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['phone'],$_POST['size'],$_POST['date'],$_POST['depart'],$_POST['message']);
}
```

Then my basic form without the div tagging so you'll need to tweak slightly:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Fname">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="text" name="phone">
    <input type="text" name="size">
    <input type="text" name="date">
    <input type="text" name="depart">
    <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="sendIt">
</form>
```

This is a very basic one with no thank you message or conditions but you can easily add conditions before running the query by doing

```
if (!empty($var)
{
 // do something
} else {
echo "you didnt fill this in...";
```